# Headless Chrome - Failed to initialize system EGL

Tags: google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to get headless Chrome to get along with a GPU.

I use the following chrome args to run headless Chrome, but hardware acceleration fails:

```
chrome_args = [
    "--use-angle=gl-egl",
    "--enable-features=Vulkan,UseSkiaRenderer",
    "--use-vulkan=native",
    "--enable-logging",
    "--disable-vulkan-fallback-to-gl-for-testing",
    "--ignore-gpu-blocklist"
]
```

The logs are:

```
  Log Messages
  [0409/001203.130608:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] : Display.cpp:1019 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Failed to initialize system egl
[0409/001203.130842:ERROR:gl_display.cc(504)] : EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Failed to initialize system egl
[0409/001203.130941:ERROR:gl_display.cc(793)] : eglInitialize OpenGLEGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[0409/001203.131035:ERROR:gl_display.cc(819)] : Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[0409/001203.131114:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] : GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[0409/001203.148610:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] : Display.cpp:1019 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Failed to initialize system egl
[0409/001203.148815:ERROR:gl_display.cc(504)] : EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Failed to initialize system egl
[0409/001203.148925:ERROR:gl_display.cc(793)] : eglInitialize OpenGLEGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[0409/001203.149015:ERROR:gl_display.cc(819)] : Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[0409/001203.149097:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] : GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[0409/001203.213726:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] : Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
GpuProcessHost: The GPU process exited normally. Everything is okay.[0409/001203.417906:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] : Display.cpp:1019 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Failed to initialize system egl
[0409/001203.418204:ERROR:gl_display.cc(504)] : EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Failed to initialize system egl
[0409/001203.418315:ERROR:gl_display.cc(793)] : eglInitialize OpenGLEGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[0409/001203.418415:ERROR:gl_display.cc(819)] : Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[0409/001203.418517:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] : GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[0409/001203.439824:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(43)] : Display.cpp:1019 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Failed to initialize system egl
[0409/001203.439975:ERROR:gl_display.cc(504)] : EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Failed to initialize system egl
[0409/001203.440067:ERROR:gl_display.cc(793)] : eglInitialize OpenGLEGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[0409/001203.440142:ERROR:gl_display.cc(819)] : Initialization of all EGL display types failed.
[0409/001203.440238:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(26)] : GLDisplayEGL::Initialize failed.
[0409/001203.443835:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(186)] : Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
GpuProcessHost: The GPU process exited normally. Everything is okay.[0409/001203.659936:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(393)] : InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

Can someone help me fix this? How can initialize EGL successfully?

Comment: What's your GPU? This info would help to identify possible hardware aspects.